# Dynamic number of field validation in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a form with dynamic number of rows.

```
    $("#tbl").append("<tr><td name=Date"+i+" id=Date_"+i+">"+com_date+"</td><td id=day_"+ i+">"+theday +"</td><td class=something> <input type=text  name=value id=value"+ i+"></td></tr>");
```

For validating

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").validate();
$.validator.addClassRules("value", {required:true});     
});
```

But its not working. I have gone through other questions posted here. but none giving any solution which i require. Help me out .

Comment: Please define "not working". Could you set up a test case?

Comment: You can set up a test case on http://jsfiddle.net , it makes finding the problem much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that's because you are adding rows dinamically to the dom. You should call

```
$("form").validate();
$.validator.addClassRules("value", {required:true});
```

after you have inserted the rows with `append()`

```
  $("#tbl").append("<tr><td name=Date"+i+" id=Date_"+i+">"+com_date+"</td><td id=day_"+ i+">"+theday +"</td><td class=something> <input type=text  name=value id=value"+ i+"></td></tr>")
```

Comment: ya the table gets created before i call the function

Comment: @Cyphon have you tried calling `$.validator.addClassRules("value", {required:true});` before `$("form").validate();`